# Reading JSON into spark dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning Spark and I was building a sample project. I have a spark dataframe which has the following syntax. This syntax is when I saved the dataframe to a JSON file:

```
{"str":["1001","19035004":{"Name":"Chris","Age":"29","Location":"USA"}]}
{"str":["1002","19035005":{"Name":"John","Age":"20","Location":"France"}]}
{"str":["1003","19035006":{"Name":"Mark","Age":"30","Location":"UK"}]}
{"str":["1004","19035007":{"Name":"Mary","Age":"22","Location":"UK"}]}
```

JSONInput.show() gave me something like the below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|str                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1001,{"19035004":{"Name":"Chris","Age":"29","Location":"USA"}}]     |
|[1002,{"19035005":{"Name":"John","Age":"20","Location":"France"}}]   |
|[1003,{"19035006":{"Name":"Mark","Age":"30","Location":"UK"}}]       |
|[1004,{"19035007":{"Name":"Mary","Age":"22","Location":"UK"}}]       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I know this is not the correct syntax for JSON, but this is what I have.

How can I get this in a relational structure in the first place (because I am pretty new to JSON and Spark. So this is not mandatory):

```
Name    Age   Location
-----------------------
Chris   29    USA
John    20    France
Mark    30    UK
Mary    22    UK
```

And I want to filter for the specific country:

```
val resultToReturn = JSONInput.filter("Location=USA")
```

But this results the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> cannot resolve `Location` given input columns: [str]; line 1 pos 0;

How do I get rid of "str" and make the data in a proper JSON structure? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the innermost JSON using `regexp_extract` and parse that JSON using `from_json`. Then you can star-expand the extracted JSON struct.

```
val parsed_df = JSONInput.selectExpr("""
    from_json(
        regexp_extract(str[0], '(\\{[^{}]+\\})', 1),
        'Name string, Age string, Location string'
    ) as parsed
""").select("parsed.*")

parsed_df.show(false)
+-----+---+--------+
|Name |Age|Location|
+-----+---+--------+
|Chris|29 |USA     |
|John |20 |France  |
|Mark |30 |UK      |
|Mary |22 |UK      |
+-----+---+--------+
```

And you can filter it using

```
val filtered = parsed_df.filter("Location = 'USA'")
```

PS remember to add single quotes around USA.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `from_json` to parse the string values :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = MapType(StringType,
  StructType(Array(
      StructField("Name", StringType, true),
      StructField("Age", StringType, true),
      StructField("Location", StringType, true)
    )
  ), true
)

val resultToReturn = JSONInput.select(
    explode(from_json(col("str")(1), schema))
  ).select("value.*")

resultToReturn.show
//+-----+---+--------+
//| Name|Age|Location|
//+-----+---+--------+
//|Chris| 29|     USA|
//| John| 20|  France|
//| Mark| 30|      UK|
//| Mary| 22|      UK|
//+-----+---+--------+
```

Then you can filter :

```
resultToReturn.filter("Location = 'USA'").show
//+-----+---+--------+
//| Name|Age|Location|
//+-----+---+--------+
//|Chris| 29|     USA|
//+-----+---+--------+
```